# ADB can't find Nexus 7 after bootloading

Tags: adb, windows, ota-update, usb-drivers

I am trying to update my (unrooted and unlocked) Nexus 7 2013 wi-fi to Marshmallow via OTA. My Nexus is in USB debug mode and I have installed adb on my system and download the update package file.

When I connect my Nexus to Windows 10, the system recognizes the device as Android ADB Composite and everything seems to be working as it should. I open a command prompt and type:

`adb devices`

and the device along with its id is correctly shown. At this point I reboot to bootloader, so I type

`adb reboot bootloader`

the Nexus reboots, enters in the bootloader and the following happens:

adb can't find the device anymore

the device manager puts the Nexus among the Other devices and so it appears no driver has been installed for it.

[image: Windows 10 doesn't know which drivers should use]

As suggested on numerous tutorials, I right-click on the device and choose to manually install an appropriate driver. And I expect to find Android ADB Composite in the list and instead the only possible choice is Samsung Android ADB Interface — which does not work, because, naturally, Nexus 7 is not a Samsung device.

[image: Samsung driver is the only choice]

I have tried to solve this issue by installing the google usb drivers using the 15 seconds install and it didn't help at all.

What can I do to overcome this issue?

Comment: There is no problem here. Why would `adb devices` detect anything when device is booted into fastboot mode? You need `fastboot` binary in PC which uses different protocol to interface with your device. During fastboot mode, your typical Android OS is not running (neither the bootloader has any provision for adb daemon) so using `adb` is futile.

Comment: @Firelord I am sorry, I am a bit confused: in order to actually transfer the ota file I will have to use adb sideload, so how can adb initiate sideloading if it can't find my device?

Comment: Please link the tutorial you're following. Note that sideloading an update is done when booted into Recovery mode which is not Fastboot mode. See [tag:recovery-mode]. Instead of the command `adb reboot bootloader` do `adb reboot recovery` when booted into Android.

Comment: @Firelord this is the tutorial: http://www.androidcentral.com/how-manually-upgrade-your-nexus#slide5

Comment: It is mentioned there "*Now use the volume down button twice until you have scrolled to Recovery mode*" -- which is what I wrote.  Simply boot into Recovery mode and then begin sideloading. That's all you've to do.

Comment: @Firelord I have initiated sideloading and I get error: device '(null)' not found. Maybe, I guess, that's because adb can't find the Nexus in the first place.

Comment: That is a different question and discussing it here would be off-topic wrt to this question. Please post a new question for your new issue.